# How to disable iPad Keyboard Shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard, ipad, shortcut, spotlight, sidecar

### iPad Shortcuts

When connecting an external keyboard to an iPad (presently using iOS 16), the iPad accepts in certain shortcuts, for example:

- `Cmd+Space` for Search
- `Cmd+W` for Close Window
- `Cmd+H` for Show Home

**These shortcuts take precedence over all other inputs,** so far as I can tell.  It may be possible for an app developer to override them while an app is in focus, but I haven't noticed that anywhere.

**Goal:**

Connect iPad Pro to Mac Studio via Sidecar, and use a keyboard connected to the iPad for keyboard input. *(I am presently testing with the iPad Magic keyboard & the Planck)*

**The problem:**

iPad shortcuts take precedence over sending keys to the Desktop while Sidecar is active.

Thus when in sidecar it's **not possible to open Spotlight on the Mac using the keyboard shortcut `Cmd+Space`**, because the iPad intercepts that key combination and opens Search on the iPad instead.  **Nor  can `Cmd+W` be used to close windows on the desktop.**

I searched the iPad keyboard and accessibility settings and found no possible way to disable these keyboard shortcuts.  If anyone knows of a solution, or can think of an alternative method to achieve the above goal, please suggest below.

**Note on Luna:**
I am aware of the Luna device, and am also testing one for use here. While impressive, there are some gotcha's and annoyances; ultimately Sidecar feels like a better Desktop monitor companion, even with some of its other drawbacks.  That is, if full iPad-connected keyboard control of the Mac Studio is possible, Sidecar becomes very powerful.